# Google Drive upload file using curl

Tags: bash, curl, awk, sed

I am scripting an `awk` statement and I want to insert quotations around the column of text (one at the beginning and 1 at the end of first column)

Example

before

https://otrs.com/ID=24670      2014060910001178

after

**"**https://otrs.com/ID=24670**"**  2014060910001178

so far I have

```
awk '{ print $2"\""$2"\""$0 }'F1  request.txt > request1.txt
```

but that prints a repeat of the second value and I just want the quotes to go around the first column.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Through sed,

```
$ echo 'https://otrs.com/ID=24670 2014060910001178' | sed 's/^\([^ ]*\)\(.*\)$/"\1"\2/g' 
"https://otrs.com/ID=24670" 2014060910001178
```

Through awk,

```
$ echo 'https://otrs.com/ID=24670 2014060910001178' | awk '{gsub(/^/,"\"",$1);gsub(/$/,"\"",$1);}1' 
"https://otrs.com/ID=24670" 2014060910001178
```

Comment: there is at least 10  columns after the second column, how to I keep those and simply go to the next line.

Answer (score 0):

Another for awk:

```
awk '{ $1 = "\"" $1 "\"" }1' request.txt > request1.txt
```